# Starting debugger from intellij terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04

As the name suggests, i want to start intellij debugger from the terminal.

Okay. I have linux machine with intellij installed.
The project i have seems to create some file before booting up.

So everytime i do a normal bootRun it won't run due to. Permissions.

So. I did a `sudo su` and then `gradle bootRun`.

It is working this way but now the problem is that i wanted to debug my project by setting some breakpoints but i am not able to do it from the terminal..

Is it possible to do so?

`gradle bootRun - - debug` is not an option. This does noting except show debug logs.

Comment: Good question, but the only point I can see of using IntelliJ debug mode is if you plan to hit some breakpoints in your code, in IntelliJ.  Then, what would be wrong with just clicking the debug button?  Actually, I would rather do that then execute a bash script.

Comment: Once the debug button is clicked, it seems, it starts as a normal user. Not a sudo. As i said, if i press the normal debug / run button, it won't run because of the permissions.. It needs to creates a  file before Making the server live.

Comment: Have you tried to run IntelliJ as root ? Something like `sudo idea.sh` ?

Comment: it seems i can do the same thing as suggested by benoit. I actually gave the root permissions to the application itself and then hit the debug button. It does work but not from the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried this gradle -DDebug bootRun?